# How to find a salary which does not end with Zero

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been trying to write a query where I need to find a `salary`  which does not end with ZERO

**My Query :**

`select salary from employees where REGEXP_LIKE (Salary, '^(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)$');`

Comment: If you wanted to use regular expressions, this checks whether the last ($) character isn't zero: `where NOT regexp_like(salary, '0$')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use the modulus here:

```sql
SELECT salary
FROM employees
WHERE MOD(salary, 10) != 0;
```

By definition, the modulus 10 returns the single (final) digit in the salary.  Going this route avoids a costly conversion of the salary to a string, before another costly regex check.

Comment: : Can you provide your input on this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73265902/calculate-difference-between-actual-and-miscalculation-oracle-sql

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Tim Biegeleisen anwser, if your sailary is non integer type:

1. String. Here you just can take the last character of a string:

   `substr(salary, -1, 1) != '0'`
2. Decimal, double etc:

   Here you just can just cast it to integer, if you mean only last digit of int part, for example 4 from 314.58:

   `MOD(FLOOR(Salary), 10) != 0`

   If you means digit of fractional part of the number, you should multiply Sailary for sertain x10/100/1000 number (according to number of digits after point), and then convert it to int to check division remainder:

   `MOD(FLOOR(Salary * 100), 10) != 0`

P.S. Edited by @alex-poole comment

Comment: I would read the question as looking for values that are not exact multiple of 10 (dollars, or whatever currency); so I would expect something like 10000.5 or 30000.25 or any non-integer value to fail that test. Applying floor means they would pass. (Does 12.50 end with a zero when treated as a number - where trailing decimal zeros are ignored?) Hard to tell which is actually required though. And the question is about Oracle, with doesn't have `right()` - you could use `substr(salary, -1, 1)` instead; but this seems to be the sample HR schema employees table, where salary is a number,

Comment: @AlexPoole you are right, but we cannot guess author thoughts

Comment: @AlexPoole : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73265902/calculate-difference-between-actual-and-miscalculation-oracle-sql

Comment: @ОлегБелов : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73265902/calculate-difference-between-actual-and-miscalculation-oracle-sql