# Calculate difference between actual and miscalculation

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query where I need to obtain result from both and perform minus on it

**My task**

- Actual - calculate average salary from employee table
- Mis    - calculate average salary from employee table where salary does not have zero at end
- Result : Actual - Mis

Below are the queries I tried.

Query #1:

```
with actual as (
select avg(salary) as actual  from employees ac);
,
miscalcualtion as (
select avg(salary) from employees mis WHERE MOD(salary, 10) != 0)

select ac.actual - mis.miscalcualtion  from dual;
```

I get this error:

> ERROR at line 2:
> ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
> SP2-0042: unknown command "," - rest of line ignored.
> SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "miscalcual..." - rest of line ignored.
> select ac.actual from dual
> *
> ERROR at line 1:
> ORA-00904: "AC"."ACTUAL": invalid identifier

Query #2:

```
select 
  ac.actual, 
  mis.miscal 
from 
  (
    select 
      avg(salary) as actual 
    from 
      employees ac, 
      (
        select 
          avg(salary) as miscal 
        from 
          employees mis 
        WHERE 
          MOD(salary, 10) != 0
      );
```

No result obtained from query #2.

Query #3:

```
select 
  (
    (
      select 
        avg(salary) 
      from 
        employees
    ) minus (
      select 
        avg(salary) 
      from 
        employees 
      WHERE 
        MOD(salary, 10) != 0
    )
  ) as Calculation 
from 
  dual;
```

Any solution is much appreciated. Solving question of `HackerRank`

Comment: Remove the `;` after the second line.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel : Following error I am getting : `ORA-00904: "MIS"."MISCALCUALTION": invalid identifier`

Comment: That's because `select ac.actual - mis.miscalcualtion  from dual` doesn't make sense given your CTEs. There is no column `miscalcualtion` (nor a table `mis`, nor a column `actual` or a table `ac`) in that part of the query.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel : Any solution

Comment: Your second CTE needs to have a column name (e.g. `average`), and without a description of what you're trying to achieve, I can only guess (e.g. maybe `select actual.actual - miscalcualtion.average from actual, miscalcualtion`)

Answer (score 1):

You have some syntax problems with your first queries:

1. using local scoped aliases `mis` and `act` outside of scope
2. you don't need to set semicolon in with expression between arguments

The simpliest way to calculate difference between two averages:

```
select
    (SELECT AVG(salary) as actual from employees)
    -
    (SELECT AVG(salary) FROM employees WHERE MOD(salary, 10) != 0)
```

Comment: If it will help you, I'm waiting for my `HackerRank` achievement

Answer (score 0):

I have written the answer and it got passed

Thank you to the author author @Олег Белов

**Query**

```
select ceil(avg(salary) - avg(replace(salary,'0',''))) from employees;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've listed the two queries that worked for me. (HackerRank, MySQL Interface)

Query 1:

```
SELECT CEIL(AVG(SALARY)-AVG(REPLACE((SALARY),0,''))) FROM EMPLOYEES ;
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT CAST(CEIL(AVG(SALARY) - AVG(CAST(REPLACE(SALARY, '0', '') AS FLOAT)))
        AS FLOAT) AS 'actual-miscalculated'
        FROM EMPLOYEES;
```